# Bot works locally but has issues when deployed

Tags: botframework

I am using the CoreBot template (from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4)

When testing locally, the  bot works just fine.
After I deployed it and try to Test in Webchat in Azure portal or when testing using emulator I get this error message instead of welcome card:

**The bot encounted an error or bug.
To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.**

Any ideas?
How to troubleshoot these kind of issues?

[Screeenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFD09.png)

Comment: can you run the bot on chrome ?

Comment: I would suggest you to make use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and debug you bot. Also, you could check for the error in the 'Channels' blade for your bot on Azure.

Comment: How can I debug the bot running in Azure? there are no errors in the Channels blade

Comment: The only error I just noticed is below (TurnError on the screenshot):{
 
  "type": "trace",
  "value": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: stream",
  "valueType": "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error"
}

Answer (score 1):

I normally debug in this order:

1. Check the Channel blade in "Test in Webchat" for errors. The info is normally quite sparse.
2. Check the "Log stream" under the web app resource in the portal. You need to enable "Application logging (filesystem)" under the "App service logs" in the web app resource first.
3. Use ngrok with the bot emulator to debug.

In you specific case, it think that the error message text is defined in your bot code. Maybe near a call to LUIS or similar? Try to locate it in your code.

Comment: Yes the error message is in the bot code, it's in the AdapterWithErrorHandler class. I'd like to debug it but it does not generate any errors when I run it locally. The issue is only when I deploy it to Azure

Comment: I enabled the Application logging and here is the error: [Error] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: [OnTurnError] unhandled error : Value cannot be null.Parameter name: stream

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it seems like to be a deployment issue.

- I would suggest you to double check your deployment [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and see if you missed any steps or details(messaging endpoint, appID/password) in the settings.
- A good place to start would be the [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation and the configuration troubleshooting [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).
- As I stated in the comments above, you can go to the channels blade under Bot management to check for the "health" of Web Chat to see the issues.

[image]

- Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and debug your bot locally on the emulator and "Test in Web Chat" channel using this [blogpost](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/).

Hope this helps.